Validate specific field in Laravel 10
I have a rating system with validation issues. Both fields need to be validated under certain conditions.
f1 = field 1 -> radio from 1 to 5;
f2 = field 2 -> textarea;
Here are my validation rules:
$validatedData = $request->validate([
  'f1' => 'sometimes|nullable|integer|min:1|max:5',
  'f2' => 'sometimes|nullable|string|max:255',
]);

I need to add a validation rule for f2 such that it is required only if f1 <= 3.
Currently, I have 'sometimes|nullable|required_if:f1,<,4|string|max:255'.
Here are the cases:
Case 1 -> If I submit the form with f1 <= 3 and f2 empty = It correctly returns an error because f2 is required if f1 <= 3;
Case 2 -> If I submit the form with f1 >= 4 and f2 empty = It works correctly.
Case 3 -> If I submit the form with f1 empty and f2 empty = It returns an error because f2 is required if f1 <= 3. However, it should be nullable in this case.
Additionally, I need to make f1 required if f2 is not empty.

To accomplish complex validation, you can use closures inside an array to separate every rule instead an string with pipes "|".

The closure receives the attribute's name, the attribute's value, and
a $fail callback that should be called if validation fails:

$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'f1' => [
        'nullable',
        'integer',
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) use ($request) {
            if (empty($value) && !empty($request->input('f2'))) {
                $fail('f1 is required if f2 is not empty.');
            }
        },
        'between:1,5'
    ],
    'f2' => [
        'nullable',
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) use ($request) {
            if (empty($value) && $request->input('f1') <= 3) {
                $fail('f2 is required if f1 <= 3.');
            }

            if ($value && empty($request->input('f1'))) {
                $fail('f2 is required if f1 <= 3.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);


Thanks for your response, It help me a lot.
I use the Rule class from Validation with the ::requiredIf(); to complete it.
